# Template overload only with template arguments' difference

Tags: c++, templates

I'm learning overloading in C++ recently, and I met this problem:

```cpp
template <typename IN, typename ask>
IN input(ask& str){
    IN i;
    cout << str ;
    cin >> i;
    return i;
}


template <typename ask>
string input(ask& str){
    string i;
    cout << str ;
    cin >> i;
    return i;
}
```

This two functions only have differences in their return value and template arguments.

I was told that the return value doesn't matter, **so the only thing that matters is the template arguments**.

I searched for a long time and I was so confused that I can't found any thing about it, but the program can be compiled and is running well. My vscode told me the two function is overloaded functions, so I'm confused that what's the rule has effect on this program's compilation?

I'm very grateful to every answer you may write!

Comment: What you attempt to do is called *specialization*.

Comment: "_I was told that the return value doesn't matter,_": That is true for ordinary functions, but for templates the return type is part of the signature.

Comment: "_so I'm confused that what's the rule has effect on this program's compilation?_": Why _shouldn't_ it compile?

Comment: You cannot partially specialize a function template. This is function template overloading.

Comment: What does "can be compiled" mean? Have you tried to actually call the template, and how did you call it?